# How do I show this is a proper ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

I'm trying to understand how I show an ideal is a proper ideal. I think I am over complicating it, and would appreciate someone to help me understand.

As an example:

$I = (x^{4}+x^{2}-2x+1, x^{2}+x+10) ⊂ \Bbb{Q}[x]$

I know this is a principal ideal, I've used euclidean division to find this. How do I now show whether this is a proper ideal? Please try to be as clear as possible, I've been getting myself confused for hours now.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you pointed out, use the euclidean algorithm to find a $P\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$ so that $
I=(P)
$.

If $P$ is not a constant, then $P+1$ is not in $I$. This is because if $Q=P+1$ where in $I$ then diving $P$ by $Q$ we obtain, $P=Q\cdot M+R$ where deg($R$)$<$deg(P), since $R=P-Q\cdot M$, $R\in I$. But since it's degree is strictly smaller than it's generator, $R=0$. Which is absurd.

Therefore $I$ is proper(because we found an element in $I$ not in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$)

Conversely, if $I$ is a constant, by Bezout theorem $\exists \lambda, \mu$ so that $\lambda\cdot(x^{4}+x^{2}-2x+1)$ $+$ $\mu\cdot(x^{2}+x+10)=1$, so $1\in\mathbb{Q}$ and so $I=\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: Ok, I found a (P) as 7825/256. Does this mean that this is not proper, because P+1 is a constant?

Comment: Yeah, that means there are coprime, and by Bezout theorem, they generate $\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: @Emily I edited the question to clarify, If you find anything questionable or unclear please tell me so I can clarify/correct it.

Comment: @Emily The argument in the second paragraph is more roundabout than need be. More simply, since the coef ring is a domain, every nonzero element $ pf\in (p)$ has degree $\ge \deg p,\,$ so if $\deg p \ge 1$ then $(p)$ contains no polynomials of degree zero, so $\,1\not\in (p),\,$ so $(p)$ is proper.

Comment: @BillDubuque You're right, of course